# Zeroclipboard: Copy content from a div, new paragraph tags not kept

Tags: javascript, html

I created on page where users can select from a drop down menu several email templates in an editable div (to highlight some elements). I use zeroclipboard for them being able to copy / paste the content to an email in our online application

If a template is selected and pasted immediately, it works perfectly. When you add a line, the code creates a paragraph, which is fine, but when you paste it, new

tags are removed

I checked the content of my clipboard and I can see that the new paragraph is ignored. New text is added straight after the last word of the previous paragraph

After some investigations I found in zeroclipboard documentation this:

```
client.on('copy', function(event) {
    var text = document.getElementById('yourTextArea').value;
    var windowsText = text.replace(/\n/g, '\r\n');
    event.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', windowsText);
});
```

The code of my page is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/zeroclipboard/dist/ZeroClipboard.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
var clip = new ZeroClipboard($("#d_clip_button"));
 });
</script>

<div id ="temp_content" class="temp_content border" contenteditable></div>

<button class='my_clip_button submit' data-clipboard-target='temp_content' data-clipboard-text='Default clipboard text from attribute' id='d_clip_button' name='d_clip_button' title='Click me to copy to clipboard.' >Copy to Clipboard</button>
```

I can't find a way to combine both. It seems working fine with a textarea but not with a div. My knowledge in JS is not good enough and I can't count how many websites I went trying to find an answer without success.

Any advises?